# Configure Ant to Use GNU Tar on Mac

Tags: macos, ant, tar

On my Mac, `tar` defaults to BSD tar.

```
$ tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

There is a GNU tar that I can invoke with `gnutar`.

```
$ gnutar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.17
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

With [Ant Tar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html), how do I configure it to use the GNU tar?

Answer (score 1):

As @Raghuram wrote, modern versions of Ant do not use an external `tar` program; instead, they have their own pure-Java implementation.  However, you can produce behavior **similar** to GNU tar by using the  `longfile="gnu"` attribute.  From the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html):

> If the loss of path or file information is not acceptable, and it rarely is, longfile may be set to the value gnu. The tar task will then produce a GNU tar file which can have arbitrary length paths. Note however, that the resulting archive will only be able to be untarred with GNU tar.

Answer (score 0):

[ant tar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html) does not use the system `tar` command.  Thus the question of configuring an alternate tar implementation does not arise.

Comment: Did you mean that Ant has its own implementation of _tar_? I was interested in knowing whether the tar file created by Ant can properly be _untar_-ed using different implementation of `tar`.